# Even unimodular lattices with root system $32 A_1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, lattices, root-systems, euclidean-lattices

I'm studying Venkov's proof of the classification of even unimodular rank 24 lattices, and it prompted the following question.

For an even unimodular lattice $L$, let $R(L)= \{ x \in L : (x,x) =2\}$ be its root system.

**Question.** Can one "roughly" classify, up to isomorphism, all rank $32$ even unimodular lattices with root system $32 A_1$? Or are there too many of these? (Note: there are at least $10^8$ even unimodular lattices of rank 32.)

*Remark.* There are no even unimodular lattices of rank 8 and 16 with root system $8 A_1$ and $16A_1$, respectively. There is a unique rank $24$ even unimodular lattice with root system $24 A_1$ by the work of Niemeier (and Venkov).

Any comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even unimodular lattices of rank $n$ with root system $n\cdot A_1$
correspond bijectively with Type II codes of length $n$ and minimal
weight at least $8$.  ("Type II" = self-dual and doubly even.)
The results you quote for $n=8,16,24$ correspond to the fact that
there's no such code for $n=8$ and $n=16$,
and a unique one for $n=24$ (the extended binary Golay code).
For $n=32$ there are five such codes according to

> John H. Conway and Vera S. Pless, On the enumeration of self-dual codes,
>   *J. Combin. Theory Ser. A* **28** (1980), 26$-$53.

Therefore there are $5$ even unimodulars of rank $32$ with roots $32A_1$.
For $n=40$ the count is
[at least 17493](http://llama.mshri.on.ca/~king/ok-codes.pdf)
(Oliver King, 2001).

The correspondence is via what's called "Construction A" in SPLAG =

> John H. Conway and Neil J. A. Sloane,
>   *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups*.
>   New York: Springer-Verlag, 1998.

This construction associates to any length-$n$ binary linear code $C$
the lattice
$$
L_C := 2^{-1/2} \{ v \in {\bf Z}^n : v \bmod 2 \in C \}.
$$
This lattice is even unimodular *iff* $C$ is Type II;
then the root system contains $n \cdot A_1$,
and is exactly $n \cdot A_1$ *iff* $C$ has no vectors of weight $4$.

To recover $C$ from $L$:
Given an integral lattice $L$ of rank $n$
with root system containing $n \cdot A_1$,
we have $L \subseteq L^* \subseteq (n \cdot A_1)^* = n \cdot \frac12 A_1$.
Lattices sandwiched between $n \cdot \frac12 A_1$ and $n \cdot A_1$
correspond bijectively with subgroups of the quotient group
$(n \cdot \frac12 A_1) / (n \cdot A_1) \cong ({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})^n$.
A subgroup of $({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})^n$ is a linear code $C$,
and we soon confirm that $L \cong L_C$.

Answer (score 2):

Another construction (basically, different terminology, but the same outcome) is the maximal (of rank 16) isotropic subgroups in the discriminant group (in the sense of Nikulin) of $32A_1$, which is $32\langle\frac12\rangle$, **not** containing a sum of four generators. This is a finite problem, but I wouldn't do that manually.